# SwiftUI: Core Data list doesn't update as relationship property changes

Tags: swiftui, core-data, swiftui-list

I have a simple use-case where I have a Core Data model with an `Item` (which has a 'timestamp' property) and a one-to-one relationship with `Tag` (which has a 'tagName' property). I want to use SwiftUI to show a list of Items, and in each row, I show the item's timestamp and the tag.tagName if it's available.

The problem I'm running into is if I update the tagName associated with an item, it doesn't automatically refresh in the SwiftUI view. Any updates to `Item` will automatically refresh, and if I restart the app, it'll pick up the change as well ... but it doesn't happen automatically.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            List {
                Section {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                            
                        VStack (alignment: .leading){
                            Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                            
                            if let tag = item.tag, let name = tag.tagName {
                                Text("Tag: \(name)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                } header: {
                    Text("Items")
                }
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
                
                ToolbarItem (placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: addTagItem) {
                        Label("Add Tag", systemImage: "tag")
                    }
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    Button(action: editTagItem) {
                        Label("Change Tag Name", systemImage: "phone")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()
            
            try? viewContext.save()
        }
    }

    private func addTagItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Tag(context: viewContext)
            newItem.tagName = "Design"

            if let item = items.first {
                item.tag = newItem
            }
            try? viewContext.save()
        }
    }
    private func editTagItem() {
        withAnimation {
            if let item = items.first, let tag = item.tag  {
                tag.tagName = "changed"
            }
            
            try? viewContext.save() // <-- should update the List, but doesn't
            
            if let item = items.first, let tag = item.tag {
                tag.objectWillChange.send() // tried this, doesn't work
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I added toolbar buttons to test out the scenario of adding a new Item, a new Tag, and setting the first item's tag to the first Tag, then one to change the name of the tag. The first 2 functions work fine, but changing the tagName doesn't update the list view.

It seems like the SwiftUI `@FetchRequest` is listening to changes to `Item` only. I guess this is similar to `NSFetchedResultsController` which would do the same, but I was hoping SwiftUI would improve this situation. In other questions I looked at, `objectWillChange.send` seems to help, but it doesn't seem to fix my issue.

In any case, what's the best way to get the full List to refresh if a relationship property changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `@ObservedObject var tag: Tag`

Comment: Ah, I just had to spin out the `Text("Tag: \(name)")` into it's own struct with the `tag` as an `@ObservedObject` and it works!